# Use a python file as qt5 file

Tags: python, io, pyqt, pyqt5

Say I have the following in Python:

```
with open('/path/to/some/video.mp4', 'rb') as testVid:
    qfile = QBuffer(testVid)
```

I am using [PyQt5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/).

What I'm trying to do is to convert the `testVid` to a [`QIODevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html), but the above throws an exception.

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QBuffer(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type '_io.BufferedReader'
  QBuffer(QByteArray, parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type '_io.BufferedReader'
```

The reason I do not want to simply open the file as a `QFile` is because my actual source ([picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) is a `bytes-like-object` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o), so I need this method to work with any arbitrary stream.

How would I go about this?
Thank you.

Comment: It confuses me a bit because you want to use QBuffer....

Comment: @eyllanesc not necessarily qbuffer; Any QIODevice will do.

Comment: And why a QIODevice? I think it's an XY problem. You could explain your underlying problem so that the problem is less restrictive since there may be other classes that do what you want but with your restriction it is difficult to understand.

Comment: @eyllanesc the qiodevice is used in my qt application that expects such.

Comment: @eyllanesc The actual problem is that I have a picamera which can stream to a BytesIO in-memory file, but I want to use this stream in my qt app which needs a QIODevice

Comment: For me, QIODevice is equivalent to a BufferedIOBase, that is, they implement the same concept but in 2 different projects: python and Qt, perhaps a class that inherits from QIODevice that internally uses a BufferedIOBase as a source of information.

Comment: @eyllanesc, this is precisely what I am looking to do. At this point I think I will just go ahead and subclass `QIODevice` and override `readData` and `writeData` as suggested. I was just interested in finding out if something already exists that can do this

Comment: Put that problem (the picamera thing) and maybe it will be easier to help you since I think that it is not necessary to use QIODevice, and if it was it would not necessarily work since a video is not only a set of bytes but they have a certain structure ( a format that has rules, is not the same mp4 as AVI).

Comment: You could use the code you use to read the information of the picamera, in addition to the code where you need to use QIODevice to see how to make the connection.